# Inconsistent Convert.ToDouble(decimal) results

Tags: c#

I upgraded a calculation program and found the results changed unexpectedly.
I've located the problem, but have no idea how this can happen or how to solve it.

The result difference is caused by this statement

```
Convert.ToDouble(0.0000000035141287671294348266M)
```

When I open two Visual Studio Community 2015 instances to run both the new and the old program, set a break point before the statement and evaluate it in the Immediate Window, I can get two results.
One is

```
3.514128767129435E-09
```

and the other is

```
3.5141287671294345E-09
```

It seems the former is correct (4348266 rounded to 435), but if I break the former program immediately after it is started and evaluate again, the result becomes the latter.

It's not a huge difference but the behavior scares me. Which one should be the correct result? How can I avoid the problem?

Comment: When you say 'upgraded' what do you mean? What has changed between the two versions?

Comment: UI, refactoring, etc. A lot has been changed. The old program was developed in VS2010 and recompiled in VS2015. The same .NET framework 4.0 is used.

Comment: VS version has nothing to do with the actual runtime and libraries provided. If the .NET framework version hasn't changed, there shouldn't be any effect to the implementation. In general, when you truncate a `decimal` to a `double`, you loose precision, that is exactly why you should be using `decimal` if that is important to you. If precision isn't guaranteed for the 16th digit, you cannot assume anything about it.

Comment: I know I will lose precision, but shouldn't I lose the same precision? What has caused the different result then?

Comment: nope, when you represent a number as a double it can be represented various ways, so you can't be sure that the same operation could provide exactly same values when talking about precision. The values can be close, but not the same representation always f the last digits

Comment: @lya That's exactly the thing with undefined behavior, it's *undefined*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within what the guranteed precision of a double actually is.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) it is 15-16 digits, and regarding your example, the difference is only visible at the 16th digit.

Comment: Yes, I checked this MSDN page before. But shouldn't it give the same results in the same version of VS for the same statement, no mater what the precision is?

Comment: As said, the precision is 15 or 16 digits. In one case, it is 15 digits (correctly rounded to 435 in the end) in the other case it is 16 digits (rounded to 4345 in the end). So it would be safe to assume, never expect to be more precise than 15 digits with a double.